# data migration without using data loader

Tags: migration

Is there any tool for data migration without using data loader.Data migration shoud takes place once in 15 minutes from any source to salesforce object.I have tried import2 but it dosnt work..

Comment: It's important to note that Import2 is not built for ongoing syncing of data, but if there was something incorrect about how the data was imported we would be happy to look into this!

Answer (score 0):

There are a hell lot of Tools Informatica, ETL Tools, Data2CRM, Hubspot, DBAmp, MuleSoft for the bulk data loads.

Refer the links:

- https://www.data2crm.com/migration/crm/salesforce-migration-service/
- http://cloudanalogy.com/10-salesforce-best-data-migration-tools-2015/
- http://suyati.com/top-10-etl-tools-salesforce-data-migration/

Thanks,
Vipul